# AWS Backup copy job costs when existing snapshot exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-backup

I have been trying to contact AWS and look for information in their own knowledge articles but haven't been successful.

I'm trying to figure out how the billing works for AWS Backup.

Let's say I have a 100gb bucket and I back it up daily with a retention of 31 days in region eu-central-1.

I then also create a copy job that moves the backup to a secondary vault in the region eu-north-1.

On the 1st day I pay the full price for copying 100gb from eu-central-1 to eu-north-1.

On the 2nd day I have added 10gb of data and made some modifications to existing files.

Will my copy job on the 2nd day be billed for a transfer of 110gb to eu-north-1 or only the delta(The 10gb + changes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, to answer my own question. The copy job on the second day will only be billed for the extra data and not the full size.

I used AWS support as well as my own tests to confirm the result.

Answer (score 1):

Billing in AWS is complex. Everything costs money, even things you think probably won't, probably will cost money. In this example you are likely going to be charged ingress/egress charges, backup storage charges for the services you use and all the supporting services.

Take a look at https://calculator.aws/ for an idea for what things cost. It's sometimes easier to get a rough guide from the pricing pages and this calculator, turn something on and keep a close eye on it in the early days to make sure this matches your expectation.

For finer grained control over billing, make sure you tag your resources to help you break down costs associated with your financial metrics to help to keep track better.

Not much of a specific answer, but hope that helps to get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Well yeah, as you said it does not answer the specific question of wether I will be billed for just the delta or the entire transfer after an initial backup has run. I will conduct some tests and update this question with an answer once I've found my answer.